# Clickable area on Core Text CTFrame

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-text

I have some CTFrame columns of text placed on a UIScrollView and I made a selection tool to be able to select and highlight the text, as shown on image bellow.

I'd like to be able to click the selection, so the rectangles are UIButtons with 50% opacity, over the CTFrame.

The problem is the following: By some reason, the buttons TouchUpInside event isn't triggered and I think that if the highlight were placed bellow CTFrame, it would have a better effect, but I think the button wouldn't receive the event.

Any ideas to solve the problem, ie., to have a selection mark bellow text and clickable?

---

Here's the Text highlight example:

[image: Text selection over CTFrame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you placed you CTFrames to UIScrollView ? CTFrame is not  a UIView subclass. Where do you draw it?
Also check your UIScroll view'a content size.

Using UIButtons is not a good idea, It's better to draw it directly with Core Graphics.
Touch should be handled bu UIView itself and then translated to appropriate text.
Use `CTFrameGetLineOrigins()` to find the correct line (by checking the Y origins), and then using `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition()` to find the correct character within the line (after subtracting the line origin from point).

Comment: You are right, I put the CTFrames on a UIView and then the UIView on the UIScrollView. The content size is correct. I'm scrolling correctly  from the first to the last text column without problem.

Comment: I liked your solution to draw the highlight rectangles as I'm doing with buttons, and test the touch position using the rectangles I saved when I drew the highlight. I'll try this idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the tap gesture recognizer, when tapped, just checks if the tap-point is in the rect of your highlighted section.  And I think the tap gesture recognizer works with the UIScrollView (not like other gestures).